# Is it okay to say something like "The reason why we pick him lies in it that he is obviously more promising than other applicants"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it okay to say something like this?

> The reason why we pick him lies in **it that** he is 
>   obviously more promising than other applicants

The part I am not sure is the boldfaced part. 
And I know that, instead of the boldfaced words, I can simply say

> The reason why we pick him **is that** he is 
>   obviously more promising than other applicants

The sentence merely functions as an example of the usage of "it that".

Comment: We have chosen him over the other applicants *in that* he is obviously more promising than they are.

Comment: Replace *"it"* by *"the fact"*, and you have a grammatical sentence. It is quite common nowadays for *"the fact"* to be put into English sentences in order to make the grammar work (kind of like a forward-looking pronoun). But *"it"* can't be used here because there's no previous reference that *"it"* refers back to.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thank you. But does not "it" refer forwardly in the sentence""We make it clear why the concept is to be clarified"?

Comment: @Chou: you're right ... it works there. I can't tell what the difference is without thinking about it for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like a forward-looking pronoun. Other languages may use their equivalent of *"it"* for this, but what is used in English is often *"the fact"*.

> The reason we are picking him lies in **the fact that** he is obviously more promising than other applicants.

Other grammar corrections – I eliminated *"the reason why"* because it's considered poor wording due to redundancy, and *"pick"* should either be *"are picking"* or *"picked"* because of the way the tenses work in English.

Comment: Which one would you prefer between *We are choosing to go to Mars* and *We choose to go to Mars*?

Comment: @Damkerng: I didn't intend my comment about "the way tenses work in English" to be generalized to more than that particular sentence.

Comment: This makes me feel a little uncomfortable as you are one of the users on ELL/ELU I highly respect. So I think maybe you assumed a different context from mine, because imho all the tenses are possible, depending on the OP's context, and I think the simple present sounds better in this one. Also, even though *pick* and *choose* are not identical, I believe that they are interchangeable (for the OP) in this sentence, and in fact, *choose* would be the better choice because "lies in" raises the tone of the formality of the entire sentence. That's why I used *choose* in my comment.

Comment: Some examples I found (for *pick*, *choose* is too easy to find): [The reason we pick Johnson has to do with the relative weakness of the WR position.](http://dailyfantasywinners.com/fantasy-categories/featured/daily-fantasy-football-lineup-building-101/); [The reason we pick USC as the #1 college football program in history is because of where they are now and will likely be in the future.](http://www.best-all-time.com/best-all-time-college-football-program.html); [... and the reason we pick her today is her movie Innocence in which we see her in a starring role.](http://goo.gl/v53hVP)

Comment: @Damkerng: the first example you found is absolutely fine. So indeed I was assuming a different context.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to be the one to tell you this, but many grammatical locutions are not "okay" to native speakers.  For instance, you have three present-tense verbs -- "pick," "lies," and "is (promising)."  This will sound strange to native ears because you're explaining what is most likely a completed event.  You've picked him, past tense.  But your version isn't strictly speaking ungrammatical.  The other two verbs are fine in the present tense as they represent an enduring or ongoing situation:  your reason continues after your selection and so does the applicant's promise into at least the near future.

The phrase "in it that" won't work because there's no reasonable antecedent for "it."

English has a conjunction for people who feel the need to explain things -- "because."  Try this:

"We picked him because he is obviously more promising than other applicants."

This version not only sounds natural, it has the benefit of using only two-thirds of the number of words in the original to make the same point.

Comment: Thank you for bringing out what is true. I have an additional question: Can "it" refer to the clause "that he is promising ...".

Comment: I consider it possible because of the usage of "it" in a sentence, say "We make it clear why the concept is to be clarified". I think the "it" here refers to the clause "why the concept ..."?

Comment: @Chou: Deadrat's suggestions about choosing the proper tense and using "because" are sound.  Why do I say this?  I say *it, that* you may understand better. I think you may be thinking of "in that".

Answer (score 2):

My judgement (as a non-native speaker):

> a) *We pick(ed) him because he is obviously more promising than other applicants.*

This is good for all occasions. Use this unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

> b) *The reason why we pick(ed) him is that he is obviously more promising than other applicants.*

You want to emphasize the reason. You prepare the listener/reader for what comes next (your reason) with *The reason why* and then state the reason. This is a good sentence. However, if you always say or write b) and never a), you may risk giving an impression that you can't control the register of your language very well.

> c) *The reason (that) we pick(ed) him is that he is obviously more promising than other applicants.*

This is similar to b), but you elevate the language a little.

> d) *The reason (why/that) we pick(ed) him lies in that he is obviously more promising than other applicants.*

This is similar to b) and c), but a reader such as myself will think that you try to raise the level of the language even further, and thus it will sound a little stilted. Also, I believe that either *The reason that we pick(ed) him ...* or *The reason we pick(ed) him ...* sounds a little better than *The reason why we pick(ed) him ...*.

> e) *The reason (why/that) we pick(ed) him lies in it that he is obviously more promising than other applicants.*

This is almost like d), but it sounds wrong. One could argue that it's grammatical, but it's probably as good as *I'd like to introduce you to him that is standing by me.* One problem is that *it* is redundant, and because this sentence uses elevated language, this *it* makes it sound clunkier than d). You can repair this sentence by replacing *it* with a noun, such as *the fact*, *the idea*, *the belief*, *the assumption*, *the assertion*, and such. (*The fact* is the best choice, in my opinion.)