# "The way" vs "how"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, relative-clauses, ambiguity

> 'The way' and 'how' are not used together.

I know the way how he did it. (Incorrect).

I know the way he did it. (Correct)

Or,

I know how he did it. (Correct)

But

> "I know the reason why he did it."
>
> "I know the time when he did it."
>
> "I know the place where he lives."

These are correct.

What is the grammatical rule?

Comment: All three of the examples you labeled as correct are redundancies. Each could be expressed with just the conjunction (why, when, where). It's true that "the way how" sounds very awkward. So why do some redundancies sound worse than others? I don't know.

Comment: [***The reason why** is considered **poor wording** due to redundancy*.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/60066/126) With your ***when / where*** examples there's no particular pressure one way or the other (as regards whether to include the interrogative adverb). But native speakers are just a bit more fussy with ***how / why***.